# User selection - Get reference for future use

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, selection

How can I get the [Start, End] point of a selection with Javascript?

I want to save it in a database to highlight the same text in future.

Is that selection relative to the parent node or to the whole document?

Comment: You mean find where [from,to] character that user highlighted and save it for future use?

Comment: I did not know that the way of doing it was finding [from,to]. Now I know, thanks :)  How can I find those?

Comment: Do you really need the text to be HTML formatted? Because if it uses invalid HTML for example nested tags, or table structure, which the user can select, but it's really hard to format in HTML (think of I select the last char of a cell and the first of the second cell). You have to put a <span> or something to **every** character the user selected to format it and keep the original structure.

Comment: Moreover, it is very hard to find the original position of a rendered HTML text. Think of that: <div>a</div><div>b<span>c</span></div> This result in a simple `abc`. But if I select `bc` how can you find where to insert the formatter elements? The selection from will be 2 (in one based indexing) and the to will be 3. If you apply your formatting according that, you will be end in something:
<<formatter>di</formatter>v>a</div><div>b<span>c</span></div> which isn't you want.

Comment: The from-to approach is only works with pure text. If you can use it, there are plugins that can make it easy to do the job.

Comment: @Fenistil Thanks for your golden answer. What if I use plain text but include some <br> tags to simulate paragraphs? Which plugin do you recommend to "Get selection range and then Highlight text given the selection range in a future use"? Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you should try using PRE tags, so you don't have to do BR for paragraphs.

Second, you have to get the selection. For this, I suggest to use the [Rangy](https://code.google.com/p/rangy/) JS library. With it you can get the range by the followings:

```
var selection = rangy.getSelection();
var sel_start = selection.anchorOffset;
var sel_end = selection.focusOffset;
```

Then you can insert a formatter element into the text at the positions.

Comment: Thanks for your helpful answer. I just don't understand why people would down-vote something that is asked with respect? The purpose of a question is to get answers. If I already knew all the little details, I would not have asked at all... Thanks again, I really do appreciate your help. Peace :)

Comment: Is there any way of calling a function once the selection is done? I need it to display a comment box :)

Answer (score 1):

It's not easy that you get the text "Of course HTML formatted" for find and highlight it in the future.

From my point of view , The best way should be something like this :

Get the [Start,End] point of the selected text from user input (In the js it will be just an integer number) and save it.then you can highlight it or make rectangle around it by plain js or jquery plugins(send the start and end point to your text highlighter function). Don't forget all these jobs will work correctly while your formatted HTML hasn't changed!

I have something like your project in the past , so i did like this :

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$(document.body).bind('mouseup', function(e){
        var selection;

        if (window.getSelection) {
          selection = window.getSelection();
        } else if (document.selection) {
          selection = document.selection.createRange();
        }

        selection.toString() !== '' && alertSelection(selection.toString(),e.pageX, e.pageY);
//e.pageX + '/' + e.pageY

    });

function getSelectionCharOffsetsWithin(element) {
    var start = 0, end = 0;
    var sel, range, priorRange;
    if (typeof window.getSelection != "undefined") {
        range = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
        priorRange = range.cloneRange();
        priorRange.selectNodeContents(element);
        priorRange.setEnd(range.startContainer, range.startOffset);
        start = priorRange.toString().length;
        end = start + range.toString().length;
    } else if (typeof document.selection != "undefined" &&
            (sel = document.selection).type != "Control") {
        range = sel.createRange();
        priorRange = document.body.createTextRange();
        priorRange.moveToElementText(element);
        priorRange.setEndPoint("EndToStart", range);
        start = priorRange.text.length;
        end = start + range.text.length;
    }
    return {
        start: start,
        end: end
    };
}


function alertSelection(text,x,y) {
    var mainDiv = document.getElementById("article");
    var sel = getSelectionCharOffsetsWithin(mainDiv);
alert(sel.start + ": " + sel.end + ' ' + text);
}

});
```

It's a complete solution using a bit jquery, hope it will help :)

Comment: Thanks :) How can I get the [Start, End] point? Is it relative to the first parent node or to the whole document?

Comment: As you mentioned you don't need the code , i refused writing it for you. Wait for new edition of my answer ;)

Comment: Thanks for your complete answer. Of course it will help me to research and learn. I'm taking a look into the Rangy JS library posted by @Fenistil above. It seems to be a "cleaner" approach. What do you think?

Comment: You're welcome , I've tested numerous plugins for my project , finally i decided to code myself for better control